# How can I upload a local folder to s3 bucket with given prefix using serverless.yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I want to upload a local folder to s3 bucket with given prefix before a glue job refers to the files. I am using `serverless-s3-sync` and below is my code in serverless.yaml file.

```
custom:
  s3Sync:
    bucketName: "${self:custom.deploymentBucket}"
    bucketPrefix: "datasets/folder1/"
    localDir: ./GlueEtl
```

When deploying, getting error `× serverless-s3-sync requires at least one configuration entry in custom.s3Sync` Whats wrong am I doing or any other method will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [documentation here](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-s3-sync), it looks like the `s3Sync` requires a list of entries whereas you are not providing a list. An example would be the following.

```
custom:
  s3Sync:
    - bucketName: ${self:custom.deploymentBucket}
      bucketPrefix: datasets/folder1/
      localDir: ./GlueEtl
```